# Find pattern and insert a line break in front

Tags: regex, bash, shell, latex, newline

I want to parse a LaTeX document that is completely valid, but might be scrambled when it comes to spaces, tabs and line breaks. Because all elements in LaTeX files start with a backslash I want to insert a new line break right before every backslash and having the content behind it all in one line until the next backslash appears. I tried this:

```
cat "$1" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\t* *\\/\n\\/g'
```

1. Read the file
2. Remove all line breaks (to have everything in one line)
3. Find all occurrences of backslashes with any given number of tabs and spaces before it. Replace them with a line break followed by back slash

Now sadly this doesn't work. To be more specific: The sed command doesn't work and I don't quite understand why.

PS: I'm on OSX and would love a solution that works on Linux and OSX alike.

Comment: you may want to add newline only for **single** back slash right? not for every back slash, like `\\\`

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because of the quotes `'` that you need to use to give sed the pattern.  These quotes prevents bash from replacing `\n` by an actual line break.

If you really want to do what you're describing, with `tr` and `sed` you should introduce a real line break into your command:

```
cat "$1" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\t* *\\/\
\\/g'
```

Another way, if you use `bash`, is to use the ANSI C-like quoting (`$'string'`) where only escape sequences are replaced (but you still need to escape `\` the new line you introduce):

```
cat "$1" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\t* *\\/\'$'\n''\\/g'
```

See this wiki page for more details about [quoting with bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

And if you actually want to replace any space (mix of tab and spaces) followed by any number of `\` by a new line and the same number of `\`, you can try this command:

```
cat "$1" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*\(\\\\*\)/\'$'\n''\1/g'
```

- any number of char from the class `[[:space:]]`
- followed by a `\` (escaped) and any number of another `\` (escaped)
- this last group is captured by the escaped parenthesis
- the captured group is printed in the substitution thanks to the `\1`

However, as suggested in the comments to your question, this might not be what you really want to do to correct your Latex document (but that probably is another question).